# CKEditor iOS Get HTML Editor Contents on Button Event

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, webview, ckeditor

I'm working with the CKEditor.  After a user changes the text inside the editor, I need to somehow "Save" the users changes.

I've tried searching and have no luck finding what I need.

Someone please help, it has been a long and tough journey for me trying to get CKEditor in my app.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem.

After a user modifies the information in a CKEditor editor1 tag located in a WKWebView, you need to run the following method on the webView.

I had to add the "textToHTML" method because the HTML retrieved and placed to the string changed characters such as "<" to "<" instead.

```
    - (IBAction)saveButtonItemPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    // Save HTML contents of Editor Window
    [self getEditorHTMLContents:^(NSString *result) {
        NSString *editorContents1 = [self textToHtml:result];
        NSLog(@"%@",editorContents1);
    }];

}

-(void)getEditorHTMLContents:(void(^)(NSString* result))onFinish {

    __block NSString *content;

    // Script to get content of Editor1
    NSString *script = @"(CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData());";

    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        content = (NSString *)result;

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }

        if (onFinish) onFinish(content);
    }];

}

- (NSString*)textToHtml:(NSString*)htmlString {

    if (!htmlString) return @"ERROR";

    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&" ];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<" ];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">" ];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@""""];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#039;" withString:@"'" ];

    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p><p>" withString:@"\n"];
    //  htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br />"];
    while ([htmlString rangeOfString:@"&nbsp;&nbsp;"].length > 0) {
        htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;&nbsp;" withString:@"  "];
    }
    return htmlString;
}
```